# If $K = \lim_{i \to \infty}\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} x_i = 0 $, then $\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i =0$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits

If $$K = \lim_{i \to \infty}\frac{x_i}{y_i}$$
with $0<K<\infty$
and $$\lim_{i \to \infty} x_i = 0 $$
then will it be the case that
$$\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i =0$$
? I tried to prove this using different properties of limit, but so far I found no way. L'hopital's rule applies only when we can assume limits of both denominator and numerator exists or are infinite...

Edit: the main problem I observe in proving and disproving is eliminating/confirming possibility where the limit of $y_i$ as $i$ goes to infinity does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{i \to \infty}\frac{x_i}{y_i} = K$ and $0 < K < \infty$ we have that $\lim_{i \to \infty}\frac{y_i}{x_i} = \frac{1}{K} = L$, where $0 < L < \infty$

Then we have:

$$\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i = \lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{y_i}{x_i} \cdot \lim_{i \to \infty} x_i = L \cdot 0 = 0$$

Comment: But what about possibility where the limit of $y_i$ as i goes to infinity does not exist? How would we eliminate this possibility?

Comment: @griedman See now. Maybe the new answer would be more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x_i}{y_i}\to K\implies \left\vert\frac{x_i}{y_i}-K \right\vert<\frac{K}{2} \text{ eventually}  \implies \left\vert\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\vert>\frac{K}{2}\implies \vert y_i \vert<\frac{2}{K}\vert x_i\vert\to0$$

So, $y_i\to0$ also.